# How can I redirect a magento website which having 2 website in a domain like Sweden and Pakistan for each country

Tags: magento, redirect, web

I have a magento site which having 2 websites like sweden and pakistan, I want to redirect as well when visitor comes from sweden to sweden website and when visitor comes from pakistan to pakistan in a single domain.
as like I have a domain www.xyz.com user browse this one but we have to redirect
For Sweden   >> www.xyz.com/sw/
For Pakistan >> www.xyz.com/pk/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [geoiploc.php](http://chir.ag/projects/geoiploc/) which is used to determine country. And then write this code in your magento_root/index.php file

```
include("geoiploc.php"); // Must include this
  $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
  $countryCode = getCountryFromIP($ip, "code");

  if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === '/')
      {

        $Url = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        if($countryCode=='PK')
        {
            header( 'Location: http://'.$Url.'/pk');
        }
        else if($countryCode=='SE')
        {
            header( 'Location: http://'.$Url.'/sw');
        }
       else
        {
            header( 'Location: http://'.$Url.'/sw');
        }

        exit;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible.For Example ,
If someone visiting from India it'll view as `www.xyz.co.in` and while accessing from Uk it'll show in default as `www.xyz.co.uk` like this.. We can also access other country default domain by typing directly as `www.xyz.co.uk`, I hope this answer will help you..

Comment: No this is not like this if we have one website www.xyz.com,we have to access www.xyz.com/sw for sweden and www.xyz.com/pk as well when visitor directly browse www.xyz.com we have to redirect to user as per his country

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect like bellow code.

$this->_redirect('*/*/');

Comment: Can you please Provide me any example??I cannot understand you